# How to add a certificate to Kong. To make https requests

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509, kong

I am trying to add a certificate using this documentation [kong docs](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/admin-api/#update-or-create-certificate)

But I am unable to figure out how to generate these "cert" and "key" pem files.

I tried with public and private keys generated by puttygen and did not workout.

A sample will be extremely helpful

```
{
"message": "3 schema violations (cert: invalid certificate: x509.cert.new: asn1_lib.c:101:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long; key: invalid key: pkey.new: tasn_dec.c:1130:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag; tags: expected a set)",
"name": "schema violation",
"fields": {
    "tags": "expected a set",
    "cert": "invalid certificate: x509.cert.new: asn1_lib.c:101:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long",
    "key": "invalid key: pkey.new: tasn_dec.c:1130:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag"
},
"code": 2
}
```

This is the error I received

Comment: The certificate and the private key are in PEM format?

Comment: getting the same error, any progress?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
    curl -i -X 'POST' http://localhost:8001/certificates \
    -F 'cert= Content PEM archive ' \
    -F 'key=  Content key archive without password ' \
    -F 'snis=subdomain.mydomain.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I quite understand it, but after looking at what some others have done online I can get it to work by just having the same data in two files and then running a line that prints the data from a file, like so:

```
curl -i -m 60 -X POST http://localhost:8001/certificates 
-F "cert=$(cat cert.pem)" 
-F "key=$(cat key.pem)" 
-F "snis=domain.net"
```

Credit: 
https://discuss.konghq.com/t/adding-certificate-does-not-create-sni/2497